# How to prevent empty page after \maketitle?

Tags: page-breaking, titles

I have a few pages that I've texed. I wanted to start the document with a title page but if I do that it produces an empty page numbered '1' between the title page and the first section. How to prevent that? I tried document classes `report`, `article` and `book`, `\maketitle` as well as `\begin{titlepage}`/ `\end{titlepage}`.
 The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\textwidth 13cm
\title{Author: My title}
\author{a. name}
\maketitle
\hfill
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{section title}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why `\textwidth 13cm` after `\begin{document}`? Use the `geometry` package to set up the pagination parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\textwidth 13cm
\title{Author: My title}
\author{a. name}
\maketitle
% \hfill
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{section title}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: If you also want to align the title near the top of the page, follow Marco Daniel's advice and use the `notitlepage` class option. (You may still remove `\hfill` in that case.) Note that the page containing the title will be numbered as "1", and the first chapter will start at page 2.

Comment: Just to explain why this happens: `\maketitle` produces a page by itself (without the `notitlepage` option) and `\hfill` starts a paragraph. Then `\chapter` issues a `\clearpage`, so the (apparently) empty page results.